# How to Kubernetes Angular.js service request backendapi service

Tags: kubernetes

----------------------- Thats backandapi Service-----------------------

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backandapi-service
  namespace: crm
  labels:
    app: backandapi-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: backandapi
```

And, Angular.js request to this service but Service changing ip adress.
How to access Services external endpoint from env or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what provides your loadbalancer you will see different ways of doing this. Said short `kubectl describe <your_svc>` would return something like `LoadBalancer Ingress` firld, that on aws will look similar to `blablabla-123123.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` which you can use to access regardless of underlying IP

Comment: We used Google Cloud and  gives ip address to us

Comment: then the IP should not change, unless you `kubectl delete` and recreate the service instead of `kubectl apply` to update svc. That is a most common situation in which your IP would change